# Can I mock multi test case in setUpClass?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I use mock decorator in every test case. Is there any way I can merge decorator to `setUpClass`?

My unit test just like:

```py
    class TestCase():
        @mock.patch('some.path.config')
        def test_case_001(self, mock_cfg):
            mock_cfg.return_value = 'value'
            ...

        @mock.patch('some.path.config')
        def test_case_002(self, mock_cfg):
            mock_cfg.return_value = 'value'
            ...
        @mock.patch('some.path.config')
        def test_case_003(self, mock_cfg):
            mock_cfg.return_value = 'value'
            ...
```

Can I merge there mock to one just like:

```py
    class TestCase():
        @mock.patch('some.path.config')
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls, mock_cfg):
            mock_cfg.return_value = 'value'
            pass

        def test_case_001(self):
            pass

        def test_case_002(self):
            pass

        def test_case_003(self):
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

use the method like this,should be useful.

```
class TestDemo(test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestDemo, self).setUp()
        self.mocks = [(mock.patch('a.methodB',
                                mock.MagicMock(return_value=None)))]
        for single_mock in self.mocks:
            single_mock.start()
            self.addCleanup(single_mock.stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

There're different ways to do this. Below are the tricks I'm currently using with both python2 and python3.

Let's assume we're going to mock the function named `get_val` to return `yes`:

```py
# data.py

def get_val():
    return 'no'
```

I'll just use `setUp` in the demo code, but the same trick should works with `setUpClass` as well.

#### 1. Simplest way: use mock on the test class

```py
# test_data.py

# mock value is fixed
@patch('data.get_val', MagicMock(return_value='yes'))  # fixed value
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print(data.get_val())   # no

    def test_case(self):
        print(data.get_val())   # yes

# mock value set by each test case
@patch('data.get_val')
class TestBar(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print(data.get_val())   # no

    def test_case(self, mock_get_val):
        mock_get_val.return_value = 'yes'  # set value in each case
        print(data.get_val())   # yes
```

Pros:

- Simplest

Cons:

- The target is not mocked in `setUp`
- You can only choose either mock the target with a fixed value, or provide the mock value in every single test cases. No mix uses at all.

#### 2. The most flexible way: start mock manually

```py
# test_data.py

class TestCool(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mocks = [patch('data.get_val', MagicMock(return_value='yes'))]  # fixed value
        for mock in self.mocks:
            mock.start()
        print(data.get_val())   # yes

    def tearDown(self):
        for mock in self.mocks:
            mock.stop()

    def test_case(self):
        print(data.get_val())   # yes

    def test_case_cool(self):
        self.mocks[0].return_value = 'cool'  # override the mock only for this case
        print(data.get_val())   # cool
```

Pros:

- You can get mocks works inside `setUp`s
- You can mix the use of mock with pre-provided fixed values, or provide the mock values in per-test-case basis
- Easier to manage tons of mocks as you can write code to control them.

Cons:

- Would have to write more code for even simple tasks.

---

Bonus tip:

Don't use `patch` on `setUp` directly, because modifying the signature of `setUp`s causes PyCharm complaining about it:

> Signature of method 'TestMockedSetup.setUp()' does not match signature of base method in class 'TestCase'

More seriously, the mock only works inside `setUp`, and would be restored to unmocked in your test cases, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just setUp the mock and use `self`:

```
class TestName(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('some.path.config')
    def setUp(self, mock_cfg):
        self.mock_cfg = mock_cfg
        self.mock_cfg.return_value = 'value'
        ...

    def test_case_001(self):
        ... # use self.mock_cfg

    def test_case_002(self):
        ... # use self.mock_cfg

    ...
```